# Let $T_n=\{11(k+h)+10(n^k+n^h)\mid1\leq k,h \leq 10\}$ for $n\in\mathbb N$. Find all $n$ such that there is no $a\neq b\in T_n$ with $110 \mid (a-b)$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

With every positive integer $n$, we have a set $T_n=\{11(k+h)+10(n^k+n^h) \mid 1\leq k,h \leq 10\}$. Find all $n$ such that there is no $a\neq b\in T_n$ with $110 \mid (a-b)$.

I tried to divided it into some case with $n\leq 11$, and then to discard the case not right. Is there some other way to solve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "$a\neq b\in T_n$ "? Do you want a number "$n$" such $T_n$ have only 1 element inside it?

Comment: @FareedAF I think OP meant for any $a,b\in T_n,\,a\ne b$, we have $a\not\equiv b\pmod{110}$.

Comment: ya i mean the same with awllower

Answer (score 2):

We can solve this without resorting to brute force.

---

Firstly, define, for positive integer $n$ and $1\leq k,h\leq10$, $f_n(k,h)=11(k+h)+10(n^k+n^h)$. Then the condition $\exists a,b\in T_n$ such that $a\ne b$ and $a\equiv b\pmod{110}$ is equivalent with the conditions below.
$$\begin{cases}
n^{k_1}+n^{h_1}&\equiv n^{k_2}+n^{h_2}\pmod{11}\\
k_1+h_1&\equiv k_2+h_2\pmod{10}\\
f_n(k_1,h_1)&\ne f_n(k_2,h_2)
\end{cases}.$$

If $(k_1,h_1,k_2,h_2)$ satisfies the above congruences, then call it a valid pair.

---

If $n^5\equiv1\pmod{11}$, then $n^1\equiv n^6\pmod{11}$ and $n^2\equiv n^7\pmod{11}$. Also $1+2\equiv6+7\pmod{10}$, so such an $n$ does not satisfy the conditions. By the same token, if $n\equiv-1\pmod{11}$ then $n$ does not satisfy the condition. Hence all that rest are those $n$ such that if $n^k\equiv1\pmod{11}$ then $10\mid k$, i.e. primitive roots of $11$, which are $\equiv2,6,7,8\pmod{11}$.

So let $n$ be a primitive root modulo $11$.

Then the condition $n^{k_1}+n^{h_1}\equiv n^{k_2}+n^{h_2}\pmod{11}$ becomes 
$$n^{k_1}+n^{h_1}\equiv n^{k_2}+n^{k_1+h_1-k_2}\pmod{11}.$$
Hence $n^{k_2}$ satisfies the equation $$x^2-(n^{k_1}+n^{h_1})x+n^{k_1+h_1}\equiv0\pmod{11}.$$
But $x^2-(n^{k_1}+n^{h_1})x+n^{k_1+h_1}=(x-n^{k_1})(x-n^{h_1})$, thus $n^{k_2}$ is congruent modulo $11$ to either $n^{k_1}$ or $n^{h_1}$. Since $n$ is a primitive root modulo $11$, this implies that $k_2=k_1$ or $k_2=h_1$. This shows that $f_n(k_1,h_1)=f_n(k_2,h_2)$, and hence $(k_1,h_1,k_2,h_2)$ is not a valid pair.

Therefore indeed for $n\equiv2,6,7,8\pmod{11}$, there are no valid pairs, i.e. such $n$ are what we are looking for.

---

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

We can find $n\pmod{110}$. Here is a simple Python code(maybe it can be optimized, comment about optimization are welcome) you can use to find all $n\pmod{110}$.

In this program, first storing the values in the set $T_n$ using `t(n)` function in the program. Then choosing an element $a$, another element $b$ from the rest of the set. But we can have same value again, so checking if $a$ is not equal to $b$, then if $110$ does not divides $(a-b)$, storing that $n$ in an array and printing the array as a set.

The $n$ values for which $T_n$ satisfies the property are: 
$$n\equiv 2, 6, 7, 8, 13, 17, 18, 19, 24, 28, 29, 30, 35, 39, 40, 41, 46, 50, 51, 52, 57, 61, 62, 63, 68, 72,\\ 73, 74, 79, 83, 84, 85, 90, 94, 95, 96, 101, 105, 106, 107\pmod{110}$$

```
def t(n):
  arr=[]
  for k in range(1,11,1):
    for h in range(1,11,1):
      val=11*(k+h)+10*(n**k+n**h) 
      arr.append(val) 
  return arr 

st=[]
for n in range(1,110): 
  arr=t(n) 
  flag=0
  for i in range(len(arr)): 
    for j in range(i+1,len(arr)):  
      if(arr[i]!=arr[j]): 
        if((arr[i]-arr[j])%110==0): 
          flag=1
          break
    if(flag==1): 
      break 
  if(flag==1):
    continue
  st.append(n)
print(set(st)) # prints all n in that range
print(len(st))
```

You can run it online [here](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/) by pasting the above code and choosing `Python 3` from left column there. After pasting press the `Run` button.

---

**Edit**:(thanks to @John for his valuable comment)

Suppose $n_0$ is a solution. Then as in the second term we have a factor of $10$, so, if $n_1\equiv n_0\pmod{11}$ we have $n_1$ also a solution. Hence, finding $n$ below $11$ will be enough. As we can see from above code, $2,6,7,8$ are the only $n$ below $11$, hence any number $n$ below $110$ which is congruent to one of $2,6,7,8\pmod{11}$ is a solution.

Comment: Note that if $n_0 \equiv n_1 \pmod{110}$ be $2$ positive integers, then $n_0$ works iff $n_1$ works. This is because $n_0^k + n_0^h \equiv n_1^k + n_1^k \pmod{110}$ and no other part of $T_n$ depends on $n$. Do you see this? As such, for all $0 \le n_0 \le 109$ which work (apart from $n_0 = 0$, which isn't the case here, so you don't need to worry about it), the entire set of solutions would be these $n_0 + 110k$ for all non-negative integers $k$.

Comment: Thanks, I forget abt it, that is a possible way to write down $n\pmod{110}$.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad I could be of help.

Comment: +1 for giving a proper solution. However, I suggest updating your wording in the first paragraph as it's now somewhat confusing & out of date.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's early morning for me & I'm not fully awake. You actually only need to check modulo $11$. This is because the second term, i.e., $10(n^h + n^k)$, already has a factor of $10$, so if $n_0 \equiv n_1 \pmod{11}$, then $n_1$ will be a solution iff $n_0$ is. As you can see from your set of values, for example, that $2, 13, 24, 35, 46, 57, 68, 79, 90, 101$ are solutions, with all being $\equiv 2 \pmod{11}$. In summary, then, the total set of values are those which are congruent to $2, 6, 7, 8 \pmod{11}$.

Comment: Thanks :) I think it works.. Can I add it to the answer?

Comment: I suggest changing your answer accordingly, including adding anything I've suggested.

Comment: No offense intended, but I think this approach is what the OP described in the end of the question body, with manual checking replaced by the python code.